# Constructing data separated by colons?

Tags: c

My data looks like this :

```
protocolAction:dataA:dataB
```

I then need to get the header(`protoclAction`) and the 2 data fields .

I was doing this- and told that its not thread safe and not healthy :

```
//data is global
char incomingData[200] = {0};

                 char *header = strtok (incomingData,":");
                 char *dataA=strtok (NULL, ":");
                 char *dataB=strtok (NULL, ":");
```

What is my best ,yet simple option, to extract my fields instead of this code ?

Comment: Does your application require thread-safety? Otherwise, I don't see how it's "not healthy".

Comment: when using `strtok()`, always check (!=NULL) each returned value to assure a string is available to use,  Otherwise the `dataA` and/or `dataB` could contain a NULL pointer, which would result in a seg fault event if ever trying to read/copy/etc the strings pointed to by those pointers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"not healthy"? It's just not thread-safe which often isn't a concern. If it *is* a concern and you're on a POSIX system, use `strtok_r()` instead. If you're not on POSIX, provide your own `strtok_r()`.

For a general idea, this is my own `strtok()` implementation (needed it for some DOS programming):

```
static int _isinstr(const char c, const char *str)
{
    while (*str)
    {
        if (c == *str) return 1;
        ++str;
    }
    return 0;
}

char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim)
{
    static char *strtokptr = 0;
    char *p;
    int t = 0;

    if (!str) str = strtokptr;
    if (!str) return 0;

    p = str;
    while (*p)
    {
        if (_isinstr(*p, delim))
        {
            if (!t) goto cont;
            *p = 0;
            strtokptr = p+1;
            return str;
        }
        if (!t)
        {
            t = 1;
            str = p;
        }
cont:
        ++p;
    }
    if (t && p > str)
    {
        strtokptr = 0;
        return str;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

All you have to do for `strtok_r()` is remove the static `strtokptr` and instead add an argument `char **strtokptr` and add an extra dereference everywhere `strtoktpr` is used.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you can use `sscanf` -

```
  /* Allocate memory to pointers  header ,dataA ,dataB  */
  /*assuming data is in incomingdata and it is null terminated */

  if(sscanf(incomingData,"%[^:]:%[^:]:%s",header,dataA,dataB)==3){
      // do something with these variables
   }
```

Comment: Problem with this answer:  the three pointers (parameters to sscanf() do not point to anything in particular, so when sscanf() copyies the strings, it will be undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: @user3629249 Why they don't point to anything ? I mentioned as comment in answer to allocate memory . So , he should before passing these to `sscanf`.